# regular expression for finding alphanumeric & hyphen PATTERN in a text file

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep

From the below text i want to fetch PATTERN **ALPHABATES-seprated by HYPHEN-NUMBERS** for example in this file "MGRAPP-713" (it will change for each file but PATTERN WILL REMAIN CONSTANT)

```
123.txt
REPORTS:
restrict CBD [Jawad Hameed] [2018-01-31 16:31:00 -0500]`enter code here`
debug [Jawad Hameed] [2018-01-31 16:09:08 -0500]
debug [Jawad Hameed] [2018-01-31 15:59:52 -0500]
Merge pull request #65 from HotelKey/MGRAPP-713 [GitHub] [2018-01-31 11:35:30                                                                                           0100]
MGRAPP-713 [sabrio] [2018-01-30 15:30:56 +0100]
```

I'm using: **grep '[A-Z0-9-]'  123.txt**

Comment: `egrep -o '^[A-Z]+-[0-9]+' file.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear.  Are you always looking for that particular string?  Do you want the whole line, or just that field?  Is the string you're looking for always at the beginning of the line?

Based on my guess about what you meant, I'd suggest:

```
$ awk '/^[A-Z]+-[0-9]/ {print $1}' mgrapp 
MGRAPP-713
```

Whenever you want to print part of line matching a pattern, **awk** is your friend.

**Edit**

In your comment, you clarify your objective somewhat.  Here's a slightly more elaborate solution:

```
$ awk '/^[A-Z]+-[0-9]/ {
     match($1, /^[A-Z]+-[0-9]+/) 
     printf "%.*s\n", RLENGTH, $1 }' mgrapp
MGRAPP-713
```

But I can't write your program for you.  I'm just demonstrating that **awk** lets you write simple programs to grab strings out of text files.  Like any powerful tool, it takes time to learn.  It's time well spent because, you know, "Luck favors the prepared mind."

Comment: sorry,i'm looking for the pattern which is "ALPHABATES--seprated by HYPHEN--NUMBERS" (for example MGRAPP-713 it will change with every file)

Comment: your command is fetching this whole number  **MGRAPP-686-Neighborhood** But is want only **MGRAPP-686** and its only check the FIRST word (since print $1) i want to check whole line n print only number.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
[A-Z]+-[0-9]+
```

> `[A-Z]+`  -- for matching all caps word,
>
> `-`       -- for hyphen,
>
> `[0-9]+`  -- for numbers